# XPATH for the <td> text related to the <th> Swift 3 and Kanna

Tags: html, xpath

I have HTML table data coming through like this:

```
<table class="table simple-stat-table item-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item A</th>
            <th>Item B</th>
            <th>Item C</th>
            <th>Item D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <div class="media item-minimal align-items-center">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-4" src=""><h5>Item A Column Data</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </th>
            <td>Item B Column Data</td>
            <td>Item C Column Data</td>
            <td>Item D Column Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am Trying to get the `<th>Item B</th>`,  contents which should be "Item B Column Data".

I have been able to find the `<th>` by doing the below which will print "Item B":

```
doc.xpath("//th[contains(text(), 'Item B')]")
```

but when I have tried for the following sibling `<td>` I get no data returned and I have tried the below:

```
doc.xpath("//th[contains(text(), 'Item B')]/following-sibling::td")

doc.xpath("//td[//th[contains(text(), 'Item B')]]")

doc.xpath("//th[contains(text(), 'Item B')]/preceding-sibling::td")

doc.xpath("td[contains(preceding-sibling::text(), 'Item B')]")

doc.xpath(".//tr[th='Item B']/td")

doc.xpath("//td[../th='Item B']")
```

Any Suggestions? or maybe i've done / missed something?

**Just so it is clear I am looking for the td text based on the th text.**

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `th` and `td` are not siblings as they have different parents. `//td[//th]` means `td` with descendant `th` - aslo false expression...

You can try below XPath:

```
//td[starts-with(text(), ./preceding::th[.="Item B"])]
```

Comment: your solution has worked great! the data above is just test data for this question and it works for this I will accept the answer, however when I use this solution on the actual data coming through it does not work, the structure of the table is exactly the same..? if you feel like helping further let me know otherwise thank you for your quick and helpful response.